# Center different size images in the same block size

Tags: html, image, css

I have different images encapsulated in square style blocks that I would like to always center in but I'm having a heck of a time trying to get them to do so.

I made an example of what's happening to me in similar design. Notice the product (the grill) is not actually centered in the `imgblock` container.

This starts to become very apparent with other product images that are much wider than narrow.

```css
.imgBlock {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:1px;
  padding:4px;
}

.imgBlock img{
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/2512/t/41/assets/WG-logo-short-black.png?43066">
  </div>
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/2512/t/41/assets/M1-Grill-FAQ.jpg?43066">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good read: https://alligator.io/css/cropping-images-object-fit/

Comment: @FeaturedSpace so I've used object-fit in the past, and it's amazing. But I'm still dead in the water with trying to center the image with or without object-fit.

Comment: use `object-fit` and `object-position` - see https://jsfiddle.net/uq8mta0L/

Comment: @kukkuz make that an answer so I can check it :)

Comment: Updated my answer for centering on `imgBlock`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set the image to full width and height (or as desired). Now you can add `object-fit: contain` to contain the image to the `imgBlock` and now use `object-position: center` to align it - see demo below:

```css
.imgBlock {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:1px;
  padding:4px;
}

.imgBlock img{
  height:100%; /* set full height */
  width:100%; /* set full width */
  display:block;
  object-fit: contain; /* constrains the image maintaining aspect ratio */
  object-position: center; /* default position is center - so optional in this case */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/2512/t/41/assets/WG-logo-short-black.png?43066">
  </div>
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/2512/t/41/assets/M1-Grill-FAQ.jpg?43066">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this. It has good support, too -- [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)

Comment: Beautiful. This is the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the older positioning attributes as well as the Flex techniques.  Make the main block position relative.  Then set the img inside that block to position: absolute.  Place that block element to top: 50% left: 50% of the parent element. Since this goes by the top left corner it will be slightly of the center. We will then use transform: translate(-50%, -50%) to bring it back to the true center.

More on [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) here at the MDN.

```css
.imgBlock {
  position: relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:1px;
  padding:4px;
}

.imgBlock img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/2512/t/41/assets/WG-logo-short-black.png?43066">
  </div>
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/2512/t/41/assets/M1-Grill-FAQ.jpg?43066">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't this method seem sort of a hack vs an actual solution? I know it works and I've used this in the past but if feels so wrong doing it.

Comment: What we have come to use today is because of hacking and built on foundations and principles such as these. You could argue one method over the other, but I would think it would boil down to the context and its use. Also, I mentioned another method and stated this is the older way of doing it. Without the full solution can we really say what is a hack and what is a fix to get to the next version of the project? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: flex` to `imgBlock`, then center horizontally with `justify-content` and vertically with `align-items`.

```css
.imgBlock {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:1px;
  padding:4px;
}

.imgBlock img{
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/2512/t/41/assets/WG-logo-short-black.png?43066">
  </div>
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/2512/t/41/assets/M1-Grill-FAQ.jpg?43066">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i may, the image should be in the center of the `imgBlock`

Comment: @kukkuz Why though? You set `imgBlock` to 100x100px and `imgBlock img` to 100x100% so the image is always going to be the same size as `imgBlock`.

Comment: Yes, @kukkuz is correct. The issue I was having was a dynamic assortment of image sizes to fit with a set conatiner size (in this case `imgBlock` 100 px by 100 px)

Comment: @kukkuz @robert-ochinski I have updated my answer to center within `imgBlock`.

Comment: @seantunwin now it works :) - in  your earlier answer `container` was the flexbox, now you have correctly made the `imgBlock` a flexbox...

Answer (score 0):

You can set position relative to your div `.imgBlock`.
After that set the position absolute to your `<img/>` with all coordinates to 0 and margin auto.

Remember that a position absolute is referred to the nearest parent with position relative.

```css
.imgBlock {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:1px;
  padding:4px;
  position:relative;
}

.imgBlock img{
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/2512/t/41/assets/WG-logo-short-black.png?43066">
  </div>
  <div class="imgBlock">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/2512/t/41/assets/M1-Grill-FAQ.jpg?43066">
  </div>
</div>
```